# How to make two frames drag together?(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a whack-a-mole project in javascript/jQuery and I'd like to have users be able to drag the holes to where they'd like on the screen and then press start to start playing(the moles start popping out of the holes) However, first I need a start button that does this and second I need both of these images to move together, at the moment when I implement this jQuery code

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div").draggable();
});
</SCRIPT>
```

under the divs, it all becomes draggable, but they don't drag together for obvious reasons. For example, when I move the hole .gif to a different position, the mole .gif stays in it's original position. I need them to move together. As for the start button, it should be relatively simple, but I can't figure out how to get the function to not run on load, and only run on button click. Anyway, here's my current project, it's quite sloppy, I know. :P

```
<html>
<body>

<!--CURSOR-->
<style type="text/css">
body, a, a:hover {cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-5/oth438.cur),
progress;}
</style>
<!--BACKGROUND-->
<body background = "http://i52.tinypic.com/34e9ekj.jpg">

<!--COUNTER(needs to be implemnted)-->
<b><center><font size="5"><div id='counter'>0</div></font></center><b>

<!--TITLE-->
<b><center><i>Whack-A-Mole</i> - by Steven</center></b>

<!--HOLE IMAGES START HERE-->

<!--Hole 1 Row 1-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:37px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 2 Row 1-->
<img src="http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif" style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:37px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 3 Row 1-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:37px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 4 Row 2-->
<img src="http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif" style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:200px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 5 Row 2-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:200px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 6 Row 2-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:200px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 7 Row 3-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:350px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 8 Row 3-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:350px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 9 Row 3-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:350px;position:absolute"/>
<!--HOLE IMAGES END HERE-->

<!--MOLE DIVS START HERE-->

<!--Mole 1 Row 1-->
<div id="randomdiv1" 
class="mole">
<img src="http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif" style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:37px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 2 Row 1-->
<div id="randomdiv2" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole1" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:37px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 3 Row 1-->
<div id="randomdiv3" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole2" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:37px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 4 Row 2-->
<div id="randomdiv4" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole3" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:200px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 5 Row 2-->
<div id="randomdiv5" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole4" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:200px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 6 Row 2-->
<div id="randomdiv6" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole5" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:200px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 7 Row 3-->
<div id="randomdiv7" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole6" src="http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif" style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:350px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 8 Row 3-->
<div id="randomdiv8" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole8" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:350px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 9 Row 3-->
<div id="randomdiv9" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole9" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:350px;position:absolute"/>
</div>
</body>

<!--MOLE DIVS END HERE-->

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
// Type the number of div containers to randomly display below.

NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay = 9;

var CookieName = 'DivRamdomValueCookie';
function DisplayRandomDiv() {
var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay);
if(NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay > 1) {
   var ck = 0;
   var cookiebegin = document.cookie.indexOf(CookieName + "=");
   if(cookiebegin > -1) {
      cookiebegin += 1 + CookieName.length;
      cookieend = document.cookie.indexOf(";",cookiebegin);
      if(cookieend < cookiebegin) { cookieend = document.cookie.length; }
      ck = parseInt(document.cookie.substring(cookiebegin,cookieend));
      }
   while(r == ck) { r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay); }
   document.cookie = CookieName + "=" + r;
   }
for( var i=1; i<=NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay; i++) {
   document.getElementById("randomdiv"+i).style.display="none";
   }

<!--Make counter +1 on mole click-->

document.getElementById("randomdiv"+r).onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
document.getElementById("randomdiv"+r).style.display="block";
}
<!--Make moles pop up randomly on a timer-->
DisplayRandomDiv()
setInterval("DisplayRandomDiv()",(Math.random()*500) + 1000);
//--></script>
</head>
</html>
```

If it's not possible, then oh well, I'll have to go about it a different way. If you need more information, just comment, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [helper option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-helper) of draggable.

I'm guessing you can do something like this:

```
helper: function(event) {
   var $holeMoleContainer = '<div></div>';
   $holeMoleContainer.append($('#holeImage'), $('#moleDiv'));
   return $holeMoleContainer;
}
```

This is just psuedo-code and I've never actually done that.  I've done simpler things like this where a new element is created and is dragged:

```
helper: function(event) {
   return $('<div>I\'m being dragged!</div>');
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, I'll have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a few issues in your markup code that could be done better and make things easier for yourself.

Firstly I would put the hole and the mole in the div like so:

```
<div class="mole">
    <img class="hole" src ="http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif"/>
    <img class="mole" src="http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif"/>
</div>
```

then i would clone this and add an id ... something like:

```
function CreateMoles(rows, cols) 
{
    var blankMole = $('<div class="mole"> <img class="hole" src ="http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif"/><img class="mole" src="http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif"/> </div>');

    for (var rownumber = 1; rownumber <= rows; rownumber++)
    {
        for (var colnumber = 1; colnumber <= cols; colnumber ++)
        {
            var newMole = blankMole.clone();
            newMole.attr("id", "randomdiv" + (rownumber * colnumber))
                .css({left: (100 * (colnumber -1)), top: (100 * (rownumber -1))});
            $("#moles").append(newMole);
        }
    }
}
```

The javascript could also be cleaned:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").draggable();
    $("div.mole").click(function() {
        if($(this).data("state") == "up")
        {
            var counter = $("#counter");
            counter.data("counter", counter.data("counter") +1);
            counter.text(counter.data("counter"));
        }
    });

    DisplayRandomDiv()
    window.setInterval("DisplayRandomDiv()", (Math.random() * 500) + 1000);
});
```

What this does is only set one click event and saves you setting / unsetting it.

In the `DisplayRandomDiv()` after all the cookie stuff :

```
$("div.mole img.mole").hide();
$("div.mole").data("state", "down");


$("#randomdiv" + r + " img.mole").show();    
$("#randomdiv" + r).data("state", "up");
```

Now you are using jQuery more (less plain Javascript) and you can change the number of moles there are, and they all drag together. (you will have to put some styling in there that I'm missing but it can't be too hard)

Basically working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TEUSA/5/

**UPDATE:-**

I found an error in the code. the `newMolew.attr("id", ...` line should have `((rownumber - 1) * cols + colnumber)` instead of `(rownumber * colnumber)`.

Comment: This is a great answer, I understand it but I'm confused on how to implement it in to what I have already, I probably sound dumb, sorry, this is my first actual jQuery/javascript project. If you could clarify a bit as to where all of this code would be implemented, I'd appreciate it, if not, I'll try to figure it out some more. Thanks!  :P

Comment: @steven first jQuery? well you're doing ok then. How about i get a jsFiddle going. give me a minute.

Comment: @Steven I've added the jsFiddle to my answer which should give you a basic working whack-a-mole from your code. I've assumed they are 100px apart. You should read: http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ to understand how the position works and browse http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for jquery selectors.

Comment: @Steven you will have to customise it to work as expected i doubt it is bug free.

Comment: Well, of course, I meant it worked fine with a few changes, nothing major, just minor things.

Comment: Quick question, how come when I take the code out of jsfiddle and put it in a editor I have the mole comes up beside the hole instead of on top of the hole? Hmm, I can't seem to find any errors, everything works, the random function and such the mole comes up to the right of the hole and I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @Steven in short: The css. Specifically the `img.mole { position:abosulte; left:0px;}` This will move it ontop of the hole if your `div.moles` contains `position: relative;` (and your `div.mole` contains `position:absolute;`). As i said earlier you  should read http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ Also make sure your moles have `class="mole"` (and your div's too.)

Comment: I see, I read the css-tricks article and everything you said is done, it works in the fiddle but as soon as it is taken out, the moles and the holes no longer stay together. They move together when dragged, but the mole always appears to the right of the hole, which is strange. Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I don't believe so, I've made numerous attempts to try and fix it over the past few hours, but I still can't figure it out. :P

Comment: @steven i'm guessing you have extra css moving it away from where it is currently set. I'm not sure if it is related but you have your html set out like `<html><body></body><head></head></html>` the usual way it is written: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: I changed it with no luck. :P Honestly, I'm not sure why I had it like that, stupid mistake but not what seems to be the cause of the issue. I haven't made any edits to the CSS, I tried earlier with no luck, so the current CSS is '#moles
{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

div.mole
{
    position: absolute;
}

img.mole
{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}' Gah, I can't figure out how to get it to become code in comments :P I get the whole mini-Markdown thing, doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @Steven http://pastebin.com/fJr9w198 expiry one day. That works for me in chrome 11 and IE8. For code: use the ` button (next to the number 1)

Comment: Ah, now I feel stupid ahahaha. For whatever reason when I took that code out of jsfiddle it didn't work, I'm going to compare the two and look for the difference. I must've been missing something. Thank you, I really appreciate it!